# Java swing components are doing strange things

Tags: java, gui, jdk

There is a strange occurrence with Java swing components (buttons, text, etc in GUIs) have lately been going haywire for no reason I see. Here's the three things that I've noticed happening:

If I move or click my mouse on a frame then everything in it suddenly gets black, except for maybe the buttons. If I hover my mouse around the frame then any buttons that are concealed will then be visible. Then if I start dragging my mouse around, text areas become visible. The outer boundary of the frame always stays visible.

If I open a menu (i.e. File Edit Help Tools etc) and then move my mouse around the menu, everything in the menu becomes blacked out except for the entries that my mouse has passed over. However, the boundaries in between each entry is still blacked out.

I'm not so sure about the details of this. It happens in the second video (below). Whenever I open a menu, text areas around the menu have weird black splotches in them.

I can't isolate the problem to a Java version, either. It happens on Java JDK 6u26, 6u27, and the latest update of 7. Here's two videos I made of the problem:

- [First one, when it happens to Control Panel -> Java -> About](http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=oiwupz&s=7)
- [Second one, when it happens to the IDE made for programming Arduino](http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=2vkf3ts&s=7)

Note: The IDE is written in Java but it's inside of an .exe wrapper made from [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/). I don't think it would affect anything.

The problem happens on and off, sometimes it happens and sometimes it doesn't. I can't understand why. Please help me resolve this extremely annoying problem.